# Multiple service injection in directive causes huge CPU load

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, dependency-injection, rxjs

I've created a `LibraryResolver` which is intended to load libraries via `WebPack`s "import" and then provide it as an Observable.

It looks like this.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LibraryResolver {

    public readonly math$: Observable<any> = from(
        import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "math" */
            'mathjs')
    ).pipe(
        share()
    );

    public readonly popper$: Observable<any> = from(
        import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "popper" */
            'popper.js')
    ).pipe(
        pluck('default'),
        share()
    );

    public readonly imageEditor$: Observable<any> = from(
        import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "image-editor" */
            'tui-image-editor')
    ).pipe(
        pluck('default'),
        share()
    );

    constructor() {
        console.log('new')
    }

}
```

This service is injected in a directive in constructor. And as soon as it is I have a performance problem (the page is frozen with CPU load up to 20-22%).

I apply this directive to an Input and I have about 50 inputs on a page.

So as soon as this page is being opened everything is stuck.

I remove this service from constructor and everything works fine.

The constructor of my directive what causes freeze

```
constructor(
        private resolver: LibraryResolver,
        private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) {
    }
```

And if I do this it goes well

```
constructor(
        // private resolver: LibraryResolver,
        private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) {
    }
```

The most interesting thing for me is that it doesn't even require any interaction to stuck. Only dependency injection. I've commented all the code out so nothing is happening but creating an instance of the directive.

---

### Update #1

My investigation has shown that the problem is caused by

```
 public readonly imageEditor$: Observable<any> = from(
        import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "image-editor" */
            'tui-image-editor')
    ).pipe(
        pluck('default'),
        share()
    );
```

Because if I comment it out everything works fine. Also the noticeable thing here is that `imageEditor$` is not being used anywhere yet. So this "dead" property causes freezes.

I've tried to open another page with 3 inputs to let all libraries load (by some reason WebPack imports them as soon as service is instantiated if I work in a dev environment) but it still freezes on a huge form.

Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: Sergey, could you profile the performance in Chrome? (in devtools)

Comment: @Shadow I wish I could and therefore may be wouldn't be forced to ask for help. The problem is that a page is totally frozen including devtools. Even simple `console.log` is not responding

Comment: try changing the usage of `from(...)` to `of(...)`.

Comment: Why should I create an Observable<Promise>?